# mysqld hangs when init-file used in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I am trying to do some stuff every time mysqld (version 5.1.4) is started/restarted on Fedora14.
I put the following line in my.cnf:
init-file=/etc/mysqlinit.sql
I've tried various queries in the file, even leaving the file empty.
MySQL will not start ... I get Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
I've tried enclosing the path in quotes and have ensured file permissions are same as my.cnf.
I've tried moving the file around.
Nothing in the mysqld or messages logs to help.
I wonder if selinux has to be turned off.
Did I miss something?

Comment: If you comment this line, everything works just fine? Try running mysqld manually, not using the start/stop scripts and see any output there.

Answer (score 2):

change the ownership and group of the /etc/mysqlinit.sql file (and dirs) to match the one mysqld (the deamon not the config file) is running under and try again, enable the error_log to see the output of the error.